# Add columns to a data.table with joins efficiently

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables `DT1` and `DT2`. I want to perform `DT1 = DT1[DT2]` without duplicating the data.table.

More specifically, I'm trying to update a subset of `DT1` by adding columns from `DT2` where there are matches. The default output `NA` for rows where there is no match is perfectly fine (I want to retain all rows of `DT1`). If I order the two data.tables properly with the same keys, `DT1[DT2,c("col1","col2"):=list(DT2$col1,DT2$col2)]` works (in the cases I've looked at: ie. no duplicates), but would become tedious with many columns.

Is there an easy way to do this?

([merge-like scenario with two data.tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345905/merge-like-scenario-with-two-data-tables) addresses adding a single column and [Merging two data.tables with many to one realtionship in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563497/merging-two-data-tables-with-many-to-one-realtionship-in-r) doesn't address memory efficiency.)

---

Example:

```
dt = data.table(col1 = 1:3)
dt2 = data.table(col1 = 2:5,col2 = 3:6,col3=c("a","b","c","d"))
setkey(dt,col1)
setkey(dt2,col1)
```

Join `dt` and `dt2` to add col2 and col3 to `dt` without making a copy of dt.

Comment: Switch `list(DT2$col1,DT2$col2)` to `.(i.col1, i.col2)`. For more cols, I think @akrun's answer here has you covered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32899606/1191259

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19553005/1191259 Maybe a dupe.

Comment: Thanks for the links @Frank. I just tried out @akrun's answer but it didn't work. Looking into it, I found that `DT1[DT2,i.col1]` returns a column of `NA` for some reason. Besides that though, `DT1[DT2,col1:=i.col1]` didn't add a column to `DT1`.

Comment: That's odd. Maybe you'll need to give an example.

Comment: @Frank, I just tried out a trivial example and the solution you linked worked. Going to try it out again on my actual case in a moment...

Comment: Sure. You can click "close" beneath the question and then navigate a menu to select the duplicate. I'm not sure if that'll close it or just start a vote to close it; if the latter, I can cast my vote afterwards.

Comment: Ah, turns out I don't have enough rep to do that yet :)